# Is there a way in MySQL to update a view with data from a table that is not covered by the view?

Tags: mysql, sql-view

I have two tables, test1 and test2:

```
test1

| id | name  |
| -- | ----- |
| 1  | Steve |
| 2  | Phil  |
| 3  | Tony  |

test2

| id | name  |
| -- | ----- |
| 4  | Peter |
| 5  | Perry |
```

I have created a view from test1 using the code
`CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT * from test1;`

I wish to update this test_view with data from test2.

What I want is as shown below

```
| id | name  |
| -- | ----- |
| 1  | Steve |
| 2  | Phil  |
| 3  | Tony  |
| 4  | Peter |
| 5  | Perry |
```

I am hoping to find a way to do this without joining the two tables.

Comment: Do you want to use the `UNION` operation/keyword?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I'm looking for a way where I first create the test_view from table test1, then update test_view later with data from table test2.

Comment: updating a view is a matter of destroying and recreating it, no?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what a view is. A view is just the result of a query. The "content" of a view changes when you change the underlying data (e.g. table test1) - and it doesn't change if you don't change the underlying data (or the view code, see Ярослав Рахматуллин's answer). Specifically, a view is *not* a copy of your data at the time you created the view, or a variable holding your data (that you can add more data to), or something. Actually, when you do e.g. `select * from viewname`, MySQL will basically replace viewname with the code of the view, at the time you run the select.

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand what a view really was. Updating the underlying data was in fact enough to do what I wanted. Thank you and I apologize for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Solarflare -

> A view is just the result of a query. The "content" of a view changes
> when you   change the underlying data (e.g. table test1) - and it
> doesn't change if you  don't change the underlying data

So, when I perform, `test1 = test1.append(test2)`, the test_view that I have created from the underlying test1 dataframe gets updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a union.

```
create table a (id int, name varchar(255));
create table b (id int, name varchar(255));


insert into a values (1, "c"), (2, "d");
insert into a values (5, "zz"), (6, "ff");
insert into b values (1, "a"), (2, "b");

create view c as select * from a union select * from b;

select  * from c;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | b    |
|    1 | c    |
|    2 | d    |
|    5 | zz   |
|    6 | ff   |
+------+------+
```